# MySQL - How to select only results with certain words in them?

Tags: mysql, select

I got user profiles on my page. In database, every user has column "mixes", where they put links to their dj mixes. It´s type is varchar.

What Im trying to do: I want to add a "panel" on my homepage, where there´ll be two randomly selected embed dj mixes from the database. Catch is, that some users don´t have filled anything in their "mixes" section, and some of them are using simple links - I want to display only embed mixcloud or soundcloud players, simple link wouldn´t look nice there.

My problem is I don´t know how to handle this by SQL query.

In overall Im looking for query which:

- selects 2 random users
- they must be users with not empty "mixes" column
- in the "mixes" column there must be iframe tag

I don´t know how to explain it better... SQL would be like:

`SELECT mixes FROM djs
WHERE mixes IS NOT NULL
AND mixes contains "iframe"
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 2`

Comment: Currently, your question is too broad.  What have you tried so far?  What were the results of your attempts?

Comment: I didn´t tried pretty much anything, since I simply don´t know how to handle this in one query and not to make some insane loops... I managed to write only this: `SELECT mixes FROM djs ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2`

Comment: @MichalS wildcards, and wildcards like have always been quite challenging in SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be looking for a `LIKE` for a match.

```
SELECT mixes FROM djs
WHERE mixes IS NOT NULL
      AND mixes like '%iframe%'
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 2
```

***Refer to***:

- [MySQL: Pattern Matching: LIKE operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)